# Percentile algorithm

Tags: c#

I am writing a program that finds percentile. According to eHow:

> Start to calculate the percentile of your test score (as an example we’ll stick with your score of 87). The formula to use is L/N(100) = P where L is the number of tests with scores less than 87, N is the total number of test scores (here 150) and P is the percentile. Count up the total number of test scores that are less than 87. We’ll assume the number is 113. This gives us L = 113 and N = 150.

And so, according to the instructions, I wrote:

```
        string[] n = Interaction.InputBox("Enter the data set. The numbers do not have to  be sorted.").Split(',');
        List<Single> x = new List<Single> { };
        foreach (string i in n)
        {
            x.Add(Single.Parse(i));
        }
        x.Sort();
        List<double> lowerThan = new List<double> { };
        Single score = Single.Parse(Interaction.InputBox("Enter the number."));
        uint length = (uint)x.Count;
        foreach (Single index in x)
        {
            if (index > score)
            {
                lowerThan.Add(index);
            }
        }
        uint lowerThanCount = (uint)lowerThan.Count();

        double percentile = lowerThanCount / length * 100;
        MessageBox.Show("" + percentile);
```

Yet the program always returns 0 as the percentile! What errors have I made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is effectively a rounding problem, `lowerThanCount` / `length` are both `unit` therefore don't support decimal places so any natural percentage calculation (e.g. `0.2`/`0.5`) would result in `0`.

For example, If we were to assume `lowerThanCount = 10` and `length = 20`, the sum would look something like

```
double result = (10 / 20) * 100
```

Therefore results in

```
(10 / 20) = 0.5 * 100
```

As `0.5` cannot be represented as an integer the floating point is truncated which leaves you with `0`, so the final calculation eventually becomes

```
0 * 100 = 0;
```

You can fix this by forcing the calculation to work with a floating point type instead e.g.

```
double percentile = (double)lowerThanCount / length * 100
```

In terms of readability, it probably makes better sense to go with the cast in the calculation given `lowerThanCount` & `length` won't ever naturally be floating point numbers.

---

Also, your code could be simplified a lot using LINQ

```
string[] n = Interaction.InputBox("Enter the data set. The numbers do not have to  be sorted.")
                        .Split(',');
IList<Single> x = n.Select(n => Single.Parse(n))
                   .OrderBy(x => x);
Single score = Single.Parse(Interaction.InputBox("Enter the number."));
IList<Single> lowerThan = x.Where(s => s < score);
Single percentile = (Single)lowerThan.Count / x.Count;
MessageBox.Show(percentile.ToString("%"));
```

Comment: But it is giving me errors: `n.Select(n => Single.Parse(n)).OrderBy(x => x);`, and `x.Where(s => s < score);`

Comment: @EdwardKarak just add `using System.Linq` to your declarations at the top.

Answer (score 4):

Your calculation

```
double percentile = lowerThanCount / length * 100;
```

is all done in **integers**, since the right hand side consist of all integers. Atleast one of the operand should be of floating point type. So

```
double percentile = (float) lowerThanCount / length * 100;
```

Comment: I think `lowerThanCount / length * 100.0` will result in `0` as well, since the division happens first, and is integer division.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the types that you used for your variables: in this expression

```
double percentile = lowerThanCount / length * 100;
//                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                           |  |  |
// This is integer division; since length > lowerThanCount, its result is zero
```

the division is done on integers, so the result is going to be zero.

Change the type of `lowerThanCount` to `double` to fix this problem:

```
double lowerThanCount = (double)lowerThan.Count();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using [integer division](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html) instead of floating point division. Cast `length`/`lowerThanCount` to a float before dividing.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the percentile calculation (should be with floats), I think your count is off here:

```
foreach (Single index in x)
    {
        if (index > score)
        {
            lowerThan.Add(index);
        }
    }
```

You go through indexes and if they are **larger** than score, you put them into **lowerThan**
Just a logical mistake?

EDIT: for the percentile problem, here is my fix:

```
 double percentile = ((double)lowerThanCount / (double)length) * 100.0;
```

You might not need all the (double)'s there, but just to be safe...

Comment: *"You might not need all the (double)'s there"* - you don't.

Comment: Does anybody know a website that calculates percentile, to make sure my program is calculating correctly?

Comment: @EdwardKarak just do it by hand with the formula that you've got. Check couple of cases, make sure it "makes sense" in a way that the result that you get is reasonable. Also, check some corner cases( aka, try to get 0 and 100 percentile).

Comment: I enter set: "100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100", and score "0" and get 100. Clearly something is wrong here. . .